# Variable width buffer based on axis directions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, buffer

I need to buffer a polygon with a different distance in the x and y directions.
I should add that my polygon has the following properties:

- closed (obviously)
- simple (no edge crossing, no more than 2 edges at any given vertex)
- potentially concave
- may or may not have hole(s) that may or may not be concave (this being said, 90% of the time there won't be any hole so I'm OK to leave this out)

I understand the buffer of a polygon is basically the Minkowski sum of that polygon and a circle of radius r (r = buffer distance), so I thought my problem may just be computing the Minkowski sum of a polygon with an ellipse.
I have read a lot on the subject of Minkowski sum [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06195), [here](http://masc.cs.gmu.edu/wiki/Software#m+2d) and [there](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_2/index.html) and found some algorithms easy enough to implement in Python (see below) but these are usually for convex polygons which is not my case.
I even set out to decipher [CGAL's Minkowski_sum_by_reduced_convolution code](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Minkowski_sum_2/include/CGAL/Minkowski_sum_2/Minkowski_sum_by_reduced_convolution_2.h) but it is way too cryptic for me (I am not familiar with C).

**Can you point me to a `Python` version or anything actually readable (pseudo-code included) of the above or similar algorithm?**

For reference only (this is not what I'm trying to implement):
[image: minkowski]

Comment: What about this approach : Squishing the polygons on one axis, then using a regular circle-based buffer, then un-squishing the result ? Might be a bit convoluted way of doing this, but to me it should solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by squishing / un-squishing ?

Comment: What I mean is transforming them so that what used to be a square becomes a rectangle (eg. dividing the y axis by some factor), then buffering, then doing the inverse transformation (multiplying the y axis by the same factor).

Comment: Squishing my polygon will alter its form as it won't buffer in one direction but stretch or compress it so angles will change. This may be a good approximation for simple cases.

Comment: Isn't buffering with a sort of stretch over one axis precisely what you want to do ? Here's a visualisation of what it would look like : https://imgur.com/a/fziNQDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of gave up on `Minkowski's sum` as it is too difficult for me to understand `C/C++` code.  As I was browsing one more time [the excellent documentation of CGAL for 2D Minkowski Sum](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Minkowski_sum_2/index.html), I realised offsetting convex polygons or triangles should be easy enough.

So I resorted to `triangulate` my polygon using a readily available algorithm (`'3d:tessellate'` in `QGIS` for instance) and use this simple routine that offsets along the x-axis only:

```
def offset_x(geom, offset, epsilon):
    """
    Offset a convex polygon given as a QgsGeometry along the x axis
    Polygon should be left-handed (i.e. vertices given in counter-clockwise
    order)
    """
    nodes = list(geom.vertices())
    new_nodes = []
    if is_clockwise(nodes):
        nodes.reverse()
    for i in range(len(nodes) - 1):
        a, b = nodes[i], nodes[i + 1]
        ax, ay, bx, by = a.x(), a.y(), b.x(), b.y()
        if abs(ay - by) < epsilon: # we are parallel to x-axis, so we just extend our edge
            off = -offset if ax > bx else offset
            new_nodes = new_nodes + [QgsPointXY(ax - off, ay),
                                     QgsPointXY(bx + off, by)]
        else: # in all other cases, we offset right or left, depending on the orientation of the edge (up is right, down is left)
            off = -offset if ay > by else offset
            new_nodes = new_nodes + [QgsPointXY(ax + off, ay),
                                     QgsPointXY(bx + off, by)]
    no_dupes = list(dict.fromkeys(new_nodes)) # eliminate duplicates, whilst preserving order
    return QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([no_dupes])
```

So given a list of vertices in counter-clockwise order, going up, we offset right (positive offset) and going down, we offset left (negative offset).

It is just a matter of rotating my polygon prior to using this routine and rotate it back to get the offset in any direction.

Inset (negative offset/buffer, or reducing the polygon instead of extending it) will be a little more tricky but it should be doable.